# Using Private Use Area Characters with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, unicode, font-awesome

how's it going?

I'm trying to use a unicode character in my React program. 
I'm reading in from a JSON file into the JS program.

The FontAwesome character apparently falls into the Private Use Area, and on my website, it renders as a square.

How can I get the unicode character to actually show up? The character in question is \uf0e1

Here's a part of the function:

```html
    render (){
        return <button 
                    className ="button write" 
                    onClick={this.workingLink} >
                     <i className="fa">{this.props.icon}</i> {this.props.name} 
                </button>
    }
```

Comment: Check the square. Are you sure you are using the FontAwesome to display it? Inspect it in your browser and correct style

Comment: Froggos, did my answer work?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi do I need any other packages? I'm importing `import React from 'react';
import '../style.css'
import media from '../media.json'
import { FaLinkedinIn } from 'react-icons/fa'`

Comment: @Froggos: you should check in your browser (inspection tools/developer tools). There you should find where there is a problem (e.g. the selected font). Until we understand the problem, there is not way to find solutions.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`?

```
return (
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.icon}}></div>
)
```

Comment: Tried this, unfortunately, this didn't work. I'm getting the same result.